# Wordpress rewrite css rule

Tags: css, wordpress, query-string, browser-cache

I generate css dynamically using `query_vars`.

Right now the url of query var is http://example.com/index.php?loadcss=mycss

How can I rewrite those urls into http://example.com/css/mycss.css instead of using query string that cannot cached, it would look better to use something like I wrote above.

I have read about `add_rewrite_tag`, but have no idea how to use it. Can someone give me direction how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use a str_replace() since the url will be the same for each?

```
$baseURL = 'http://example.com/index.php?loadcss='
$cssURL = 'http://example.com/css/'

str_replace($baseURL . 'mycss', $cssURL . 'mycss.css', $the_queried_vars);
```

Comment: of course, this is only practical if you have a handful of them. anything over 25 or 50 gets to be a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of wordpress I would just use a PHP to generate the dynamic CSS.
This is the method most people are using .
See [HERE](http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/) or [HERE](http://davidwalsh.name/css-variables-php-dynamic) or [HERE](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Dynamic-CSS-with-PHP/) for example .

You have many ways to do this technique, some of them also show style.css and not style.php on the code (actually it is only about changing header or putting php code inside the css.. )

Answer (score -1):

Try out the [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) WordPress Plugin